# String literal's passing through multiple layers

Tags: typescript

I have a type of string literals defined as `type answer = 'yes'|'no';`
I am trying to "pass down" the type. All classes and files are properly imported/exported to each other.

**File1.ts**

```
type answer = 'yes'|'no';
export class test{
    static getAnswer(input:answer){
        if(answer === 'yes') console.log('Correct');
        else console.log('False');
    }
}
```

**File2.ts**

```
import {test} from 'File1';
class sendAnswer{
    static answer(input:string){
        test.getAnswer(input); //this is where I get the error
    } 
}
```

**Error:**

> TS2345 Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'itemString'

I have many files that will call `answer()` from `File2.ts` with the string `'yes'` or `'no'`.
I know I can define the type in every file so that the proper options get passed to the top level, but I am trying to find a way declare the type at the top level, and have it passed down to the files that use that function.

Comment: Just export `type answer` and use it in other files: `static answer(input: answer)`

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thanks, worked great. Post as an answer and I will gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export/import types the same way you do with classes. So just export literal type and use it whenever needed.

**File 1**

```
export type Answer = 'yes'|'no';
...
```

**File 2**

```
import {test, Answer} from 'File1';
...
    static answer(input: Answer) {}
...
```